# Does mage power work with continuous trap monsters?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

With the new ruling from March 2020 come into affect for continuous trap monsters not occupying both zones anymore.  If they're still treated as a trap by effect, can mage power be useful?  Cards like "Zoma, the Spirit", "Tiki Curse", "Tiki Soul", and/or "Statue of Anguish Pattern" comes to mind.

There are cards to cover both the trap and monster if they presumably get destroyed, but what about equip cards, if so, and more specifically, mage power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Mage Power applies an ATK/DEF gain for each Spell/Trap you control.

When Problem-Solving Card Text uses the term "Spell/Trap" in this manner, it means "Spell or Trap Card."  Mage Power does not refer to "Spell & Trap Zones," or any other zones for that matter, and thus does not care which zones the Spell or Trap Cards are in.  Spell Cards in the Field Zone are incorporated into the ATK/DEF gain as well.

This only pertains to Trap Monsters with the "this card is also still a Trap" condition, like Zoma the Spirit.  Trap Monsters with the "this card is NOT treated as a Trap" condition, like The Prime Monarch after being Special Summoned, are excluded.